# If $AB = BA$, then $(AB)^{3} = A^{3}B^{3}$. Is this true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I determine if this is true or false?

First of, I know that $(AB)^T = B^T  A^T$. However, since $AB=BA$, I tried numerous different matrices and they all satisfy this equation. Of those I tried $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 &0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, and $A =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2\\ 2 & 2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hint: $M^3 = MMM$.

Comment: First of, I know that (AB)^T = B^T * A^T. However, since AB=BA, I tried numerous different matrices and they all satisfy this equation. Of those I tried A = [1 0; 0 1], B = [1 1; 1 1], and A =[1 1; 1 1] and B=[2 2; 2 2].

Comment: Ordinarily, I encourage people to look at examples; but in this case, I think it’s most profitable to just stare at the single hypothesis: $AB=BA$.

Comment: Use azif00's hint and the fact that matrix multiplication is associative.

Comment: Don't worry about linear algebra specific things like transpose. You can do this generically just treating A and B as symbols of the alphabet, the operation being concatenation of strings from that alphabet and the only equivalence relation coming from repeatedly swapping an AB substring for a BA substring and vice versa.

Comment: AB = BA can only work if A = B, or if A or B is an identity matrix

Comment: @Enterbot Unfortunately, this is not true. Choose your favourite matrix $A$, and let $B = 2I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Or, let $B = A^2$. In both these cases, $AB = BA$, but neither is the identity matrix, and they are not (necessarily) equal.

Comment: Suppose you weren't allowed to use the "cubed" symbol.  How else would you write $(AB)^3$?

Comment: @RobertShore, I could write it as AB = ABABAB

Comment: Now how can you use "AB=BA" to rewrite $ABABAB$?

Comment: In my opinion this question should not have been closed.  It shows a good faith effort to reach an independent solution, albeit one that's badly off track.  I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, $(AB)^n = \underbrace{(AB)(AB)(AB) \cdots (AB)}_{n \text{ times}}$.

So $(AB)^3 = (AB)(AB)(AB) = ABABAB$. Given this, and the rule $BA = AB$. See if you can transform this expression to get $A^3 B^3$—which by definition is $AAABBB$

Comment: Since matrix multiplication is associative, ABABAB can be written as (AAA)BBB. Is this correct?

Comment: @Enterbot "Associative" means you can move parentheses around: $((AB)C)(DE) = (AB)((CD)E)$ as long as the order of the matrices remains the same. Notice that when we write something like $ABABAB$, multiplication is only defined between two things, so really this means $((((AB)A)B)A)B)$ or something. However, the parentheses can be moved around and we call any such product $ABABAB$ since it doesn't matter where the parentheses go.

Comment: "Commutative" means you can swap the position of two things. That's what $AB = BA$ says. It says that if you have $B$ before $A$, they can trade places until all your $B$'s are on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the two matrices (or in general linear maps) $A$ and $B$ commute, then you can freely arrange the relative order between them. Hence $(AB)^3=A^3B^3$.